# A priori contrasts for lm() in R

Tags: r, lm, contrast

I'm having trouble with setting a priori contrasts and would like to ask for some help. The following code should give two orthogonal contrasts to the factor level "d".

```
Response <- c(1,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,4,6,5,5,5,5,5,5,4,6,5,5,5,5,5,5)
A <- factor(c(rep("c",8),rep("d",8),rep("h",8)))
contrasts(A) <- cbind("d vs h"=c(0,1,-1),"d vs c"=c(-1,1,0))
summary.lm(aov(Response~A))
```

What I get is:

```
Call:
aov(formula = Response ~ A)

Residuals:
   Min         1Q     Median         3Q        Max 
-1.000e+00 -3.136e-16 -8.281e-18 -8.281e-18  1.000e+00 

Coefficients:
        Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   4.0000     0.1091  36.661  < 2e-16 ***
Ad vs h      -1.0000     0.1543  -6.481 2.02e-06 ***
Ad vs c       2.0000     0.1543  12.961 1.74e-11 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Residual standard error: 0.5345 on 21 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.8889,     Adjusted R-squared: 0.8783 
F-statistic:    84 on 2 and 21 DF,  p-value: 9.56e-11
```

But I expect the Estimate of (Intercept) to be 5.00, as it should be equal to the level d, right? Also the other estimates look strange...

I know I can get the correct values easier using relevel(A, ref="d") (where they are displayed correctly), but I am interested in learning the correct formulation to test own hypotheses. If I run a similar example with the folowing code (from a website), it works as expected:

```
irrigation<-factor(c(rep("Control",10),rep("Irrigated 10mm",10),rep("Irrigated20mm",10))) 
biomass<-1:30 
contrastmatrix<-cbind("10 vs 20"=c(0,1,-1),"c vs 10"=c(-1,1,0))
contrasts(irrigation)<-contrastmatrix 
summary.lm(aov(biomass~irrigation))


Call:
aov(formula = biomass ~ irrigation)

Residuals:
       Min         1Q     Median         3Q        Max 
-4.500e+00 -2.500e+00  3.608e-16  2.500e+00  4.500e+00 

Coefficients:
                   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)         15.5000     0.5528   28.04  < 2e-16 ***
irrigation10 vs 20 -10.0000     0.7817  -12.79 5.67e-13 ***
irrigationc vs 10   10.0000     0.7817   12.79 5.67e-13 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Residual standard error: 3.028 on 27 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.8899,     Adjusted R-squared: 0.8817 
F-statistic: 109.1 on 2 and 27 DF,  p-value: 1.162e-13
```

I would really appreciate some explanation for this.

Thanks, Jeremias

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem is in the understanding of `contrasts` (You may `?contrasts` for detail). Let me explain in detail:

If you use the default way for `factor` `A`,

```
A <- factor(c(rep("c",8),rep("d",8),rep("h",8)))
> contrasts(A)
  d h
c 0 0
d 1 0
h 0 1
```

thus the model `lm` gives you are

```
Mean(Response) = Intercept + beta_1 * I(d = 1) + beta_2 * I(h = 1)

summary.lm(aov(Response~A))
Coefficients:
    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)    2.000      0.189    10.6  7.1e-10 ***
Ad             3.000      0.267    11.2  2.5e-10 ***
Ah             3.000      0.267    11.2  2.5e-10 ***
```

So for group `c`, the mean is just intercept `2`, for group `d` , the mean is `2 + 3 = 5`, same for group `h`.

What if you use your own contrast:

```
contrasts(A) <- cbind("d vs h"=c(0,1,-1),"d vs c"=c(-1,1,0))

A
[1] c c c c c c c c d d d d d d d d h h h h h h h h
attr(,"contrasts")
    d vs h d vs c
c      0     -1
d      1      1
h     -1      0
```

The model you fit turns out to be

```
Mean(Response) = Intercept + beta_1 * (I(d = 1) - I(h = 1)) + beta_2 * (I(d = 1) - I(c = 1))
     = Intercept + (beta_1 + beta_2) * I(d = 1) - beta_2 * I(c = 1) - beta_1 * I(h = 1)

Coefficients:
Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)    4.000      0.109   36.66  < 2e-16 ***
Ad vs h       -1.000      0.154   -6.48  2.0e-06 ***
Ad vs c        2.000      0.154   12.96  1.7e-11 ***
```

So for group `c`, the mean is `4 - 2 = 2`, for group `d`, the mean is `4 - 1 + 2 = 5`, for group `h`, the mean is `4 - (-1) = 5`.

==========================

Update:

The easiest way to do your contrast is to set the base (reference) level to be `d`.

```
contrasts(A) <- contr.treatment(3, base = 2)
Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  5.00e+00   1.89e-01    26.5  < 2e-16 ***
A1          -3.00e+00   2.67e-01   -11.2  2.5e-10 ***
A3          -4.86e-17   2.67e-01     0.0        1
```

If you want to use your contrast:

```
Response <- c(1,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,4,6,5,5,5,5,5,5,4,6,5,5,5,5,5,5)
A <- factor(c(rep("c",8),rep("d",8),rep("h",8)))
mat<- cbind(rep(1/3, 3), "d vs h"=c(0,1,-1),"d vs c"=c(-1,1,0))
mymat <- solve(t(mat))
my.contrast <- mymat[,2:3]
contrasts(A) <- my.contrast
summary.lm(aov(Response~A))

Coefficients:
Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 4.00e+00   1.09e-01    36.7  < 2e-16 ***
Ad vs h     7.69e-16   2.67e-01     0.0        1    
Ad vs c     3.00e+00   2.67e-01    11.2  2.5e-10 ***
```

Reference: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/library/contrast_coding.htm

Comment: Hello Liuminzhao, thank you very much for your quick reply! Unfortunately I haven't got the full idea yet. As I see from your answer, using own contrasts the (Intercept) is the overall mean, whereas in the default treatment contrasts, it is the reference level. But what was actually tested with my own contrasts? Since both contrasts are marked to be significant, obviously not what I wanted to test... Could you please give an example of how to test level d vs. c and d vs. h correctly so that I can learn from it? Cheers, Jeremias

Comment: I looked back to my regression notes and googled up for a while. Hope my updated answer helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was quite helpful!